# conan and cmake: get project directory from another project

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

There is project with only configuration files. I cannot change this. Someone thought this was a good idea and I have to deal with it. Lets call this project A.

Project B is a cmake c++ project, with some tests depeding on some of the configuration files in project A.

I need to find the directory where this files are, so I can parse them in the tests.

What I've tried:

In some projects I've been able to access folders from other projects. For example adding a certain directory to the included directory:

```
target_include_directories(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC 
  "${ProjectName_INCLUDE_DIR}/Some_Other_Directory"
```

but in this case whatever I try is an empty string. For example, I tried

```
message("${project_B}")
```

I'm guessing project A is missing some functionality where its project folder is exported to cmake, but I have not been able to find this.

How do I export a project folder in conan? Project A does not have a CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: It's not clear if project A is a Conan package, or only B or both. If you want to capture where a package is installed by Conan, you can use [cmake_paths](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/generators/cmake_paths.html) generator, include it in your cmake file and use the exported variables. To export a folder using Conan, read: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/attributes.html#exports

Comment: Both are conan projects.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access the path of project A from project B using the cmake variable ${CONAN_PROJECTNAME_ROOT}.

In the conanfile.py of project A, the cmake and cmake_find_package generators were used, which I think made available the root directory for project B.